# MS Access - OpenReport with WhereCondition prompting for parameters/Invalid bracketing

Tags: ms-access

In my MS Access project, I have a form which I use to gather a couple parameters. When the user clicks the `Search` button, it will run some code which opens a report using `DoCmd.OpenReport` and `WhereCondition`.

I have done this on 10 other forms, all the exact same way. When it comes to opening this particular report, I am getting errors.

Here is my `Search_Button_Click` method:

```vb
Private Sub Search_Button_Click()

    Dim str As String
    str = "[n.Complete] = True"    
    str = str & " AND [pn.Processing_Date] BETWEEN #" & From_Date.value & "# AND #" & To_Date.value & "#"
    str = str & " AND pn.Nest_Number LIKE '" & Nest_Number.value & "*'"
    
    DoCmd.OpenReport "r_Processed_Jobs_New", acViewReport, WhereCondition:=str

End Sub
```

**The Issue**

With this code, the resulting error message is this:

> Run-time error '3126': Invalid bracketing of name '[n.Complete]'.

I tried using `n.[Complete]` or even `n.Complete` but both options then prompted me saying: `Enter Parameter Value` for `n.Complete`.

**My Project**

The reports `Record Source` is set to query `Q_Processed_Jobs`. Here is the query:

```sql
SELECT nj.Job_Number, nj.Nest_Number, nj.Customer_Name, nj.Job_Date, pn.Processing_Date AS [Processing Date]
FROM (Nest AS n INNER JOIN Nest_Job AS nj ON n.Nest_Number = nj.Nest_Number) INNER JOIN Processing_Nest AS pn ON n.Nest_Number = pn.Nest_Number;
```

So I have `n` which aliases the table `Nest`. Nowhere on the report do I have `Complete` or `n.Complete`. It is only in the `WhereCondition` which should be used to filter the query results. The table aliases and columns are present, so why is it prompting me as if it doesn't recognize them?

**Working example**

Again, I have done this countless other times with other queries and reports and they work with none of these errors. Why is it happening here?

Here is an example on another one of my forms:

```vb
Private Sub Search_Button_Click()

    Dim str As String
    str = "[t.Date_Received] BETWEEN #" & From_Date.value & "# AND #" & To_Date.value & "#"
    str = " AND [pli.PO_Number] = " & PO_Number.value
        
    DoCmd.OpenReport "r_Receiving_By_Date", acViewReport, WhereCondition:=str
End Sub
```

and the corresponding query:

```sql
SELECT pli.PO_Number, pli.Inventory_Code, r.ID, r.Date_Received, rli.Quantity, rli.Weight, rli.CWT, rli.Total, pli.Total, iif(pli.Complete = True, 0, pli.Total - rli.Total) AS Balance, rli.MTR_Number, rli.Heat_Number
FROM ([PO Line Items] AS pli INNER JOIN (SELECT t.PO_Number, t.ID, t.Date_Received FROM Receiving AS t)  AS r ON pli.PO_Number = r.PO_Number) INNER JOIN [Receiving Line Items] AS rli ON (rli.Inventory_Code = pli.Inventory_Code) AND (r.ID = rli.Receiving_Id);
```

Comment: Use `Where` condition to `SQL` statement rather than filtering report. There is no field having `n.Complete` in your SQL query. So how report will be filtered by `n.Complete`?

Answer (score 0):

`DoCmd.OpenReport ... , WhereCondition:=str` takes the record source of the report  (`Q_Processed_Jobs`), and applies the WhereCondition **to the result set of that query**.

So if you want to filter by `n.Complete`, then this must be part of the `SELECT` list of the query. Even if it isn't actually used on the report.

The same will apply to `pn.Nest_Number`.

`n.[Complete]` is the correct form (or `n.Complete`).